# Laravel4 Eloquent One-To-Many shows nothing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok. Here it goes.
I have two models to show and one controller.

PartyPlay.php

```
class PartyPlay extends BaseModel {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'party_plays';

    public static $relationsData = [
        'course' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'Course'],
        'owner' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'member_id'],
        'members' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'PartyMember']
    ];

    public function toArray() {
        $this->load('course', 'members', 'owner');
        return parent::toArray();
    }

}
```

Course.php

```
class Course extends BaseModel {

    protected $table = 'courses';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public static $relationsData = [
        'hole_items' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Hole']
    ];

    public function toArray() {
        $this->load('hole_items');
        return parent::toArray();
    }

}
```

BetRegistrationController.php

```
class BetRegistrationController extends BaseController {

    public function getBets($id) {
        $pp = PartyPlay::find($id);
        return $pp;
    }

}
```

My problem is when I access /bet-registration/bets/{id}, it return full JSON including the course relation of PartyPlay to the Course model and the hole_items relation of Course to the Hole model. Below is the sample return:

```
{
    "id": "10",
    "member_id": "7",
    "course_id": "11",
    "course": {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Course Name 2",
        "holes": "3",
        "hole_items": [
            {
                "id": "30",
                "hole_number": "9",
                "par": "8",
                "course_id": "11"
            },
            {
                "id": "31",
                "hole_number": "7",
                "par": "6",
                "course_id": "11"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I tried to loop through the hole_items of the course object, it says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. And when I tried to count the length of the array, ('coz that's supposed to be an array), it returns zero.

Comment: You have posted your model twice. Can you fix your question to include the other model you mentioned?

Comment: Are you using "Ardent"?

Comment: @Scopey Yes, I'm using Ardent.

Comment: Show the code causing error.

Comment: It returns an empty string when I tried to access ```$pp->course->hole_items``` and it should be an array. However, when I return the object ```$pp``` it included the course object with the hole_items array.